# Java Script for loop only iterates through the first row on a table

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

My for loop will iterate multiple times but any changes I want to make to the cells only happens in the first row. The counters for the rows and the cells all go up but the only cells that are updated are the ones in the first row. I've even examined through the console and nothing is happening to the other rows.

**Note**: I only want the cells with the ID's to be updated

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) //for every row
{
  for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) //for every cell
  {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[c];
    console.log("row counter " + r);
    console.log("cell counter " + c);

    if (x.id == "wed_asso") {
      schedule_wed();
      x.innerHTML = wed_associate;
    }

    if (x.id == "asso") {
      schedule();
      x.innerHTML = associate;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th> Wednesday </th>
    <th> Thursday</th>
    <th> Friday</th>
    <th> Saturday</th>
    <th> Thursday</th>
    <th> Friday</th>
    <th> Saturday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> TDR</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="asso"></td>
    <td>Alec</td>
    <td id="asso"></td>
    <td id="asso"></td>
    <td>Alec</td>
    <td id="asso"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td id="wed_asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
    <td id="asso"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `var x =document.getElementsByTagName("td")[c];` is the issue, it gets the cth td relative to the document, not the row ... why not `= table.rows[r].cells[c]` ?

Comment: `var x =document.getElementsByTagName("td")[c];` should be edited. The for loops like 
1th row 1th column, 1th row 2th column... 
2th row 1th column, 2th row 2th column...
But `x` only gathers all `td` tags like all columns though it should gather `td` tags like 1th row's all column.

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for the suggestion. I can see now that thats the problem. But I dont think i can use `= table.rows[r].cells[c]` cause I need to access the Id of the cell <td> any other suggestions for that>

Comment: @Bravo you know what? next time I'm gonna implement any suggestions into my code before I speak next time. That totally worked! Thanks so much!